# Confusion about returning 0 on calculation when the number doesn't end in a decimal

Tags: ruby

I'm new to coding and I wrote something quickly to calculate armor against certain enemies based on level for WoTLK classic so I wouldn't have to keep going back to WolframAlpha.

Problem is

```
def BossArmor(armor)

    result = ((armor / (armor + 16635)) * 100)
    puts result

end
```

Returns 0, while

```
def BossArmor(armor)

    result = ((armor / (armor + 16635.0)) * 100)
    puts result

end
```

Returns the correct amount (59.54228178125835)

Entire code if that is important at all

```
def RegularArmor(armor)

    result = ((armor / (armor + 15232.5)) * 100)
    puts result

end

def BossArmor(armor)

    result = ((armor / (armor + 16635.0)) * 100)
    puts result

end

def GetArmorSafely
    puts "How much armor do you have?"
    armor = gets

    if armor =~ /^-?[0-9]+$/
        armor = armor.to_i
        RegularArmor(armor)
        BossArmor(armor)
    else
        puts "Invalid input, only integers are accepted."
        GetArmorSafely()
    end

end

GetArmorSafely()
```

I assume this has something to do with .0 making it a float/decimal or something similar, but I can't wrap my head around why it returns 0 without it. Maybe it has to do with me converting the input string to an integer?

To my knowledge I'm just throwing an integer into a simple calculation.

Any answers would be appreciated.

Comment: See the docs for [`Integer#/`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/Integer.html#method-i-2F): for integer arguments, it _"truncates the result to an integer"_.

Comment: Note that the variable `result` and the outer parentheses serve no purpose; just write `puts (armor / (armor + 16635.0)) * 100`, or, perhaps better for readability, `puts 100 * (armor / (armor + 16635.0))` (even though the outer parentheses are not needed).

Answer (score 1):

When dividing two integers, the result is an integer. E.g.

```
irb(main):001:0> 1 / 2
=> 0
```

But if one of these is a floating point number, the result will be a floating point number.

```
irb(main):002:0> 1 / 2.0
=> 0.5
```

An `Integer` can be converted to a `Float` with the`#to_f` method.

```
irb(main):005:0> 1.to_f / 2
=> 0.5
```

It's also possible to use the `#fdiv` method.

```
irb(main):007:0> 1.fdiv(2)
=> 0.5
```